# Plot different occurrences per date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-science

I have a dataset with many columns and two of them are:

| Type of vaccine | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 01-01-2021 |
| A | 01-01-2021 |
| B | 01-01-2021 |
| C | 02-01-2021 |
| B | 02-01-2021 |
| D | 03-01-2021 |
| E | 04-01-2021 |
| ... | ... |

I want to plot a line graph showing every type of vaccine and it's amount per date.

I have a plot like this
`plot2 = df.value_counts('vacina_dataaplicacao').sort_values().plot(kind='line', cmap='plasma')` but it only show one line and the totals per date. I need to separate it, one line for each type of vaccine.

[image: There's the result of that graph I already have.]

Comment: Be sure to convert the `'Date'` column to a `datetime dtype` with `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.date`, and then use `seaborn.catplot`: `sns.catplot(data=df, y='Date', hue='Type of vaccine', kind='count', height=6, aspect=1)`

Comment: This is discrete data and `pd.crosstab(df.Date, df['Type of vaccine']).plot(figsize=(12, 5))` is difficult to read.

Comment: Barplot version without seaborn: `pd.crosstab(df.Date, df['Type of vaccine']).plot(figsize=(12, 5), kind='bar')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one line:

```py
pd.crosstab(pd.to_datetime(df['Date']), df['Type of vaccine']).cumsum().plot()
```

[image]

**Credit to @TrentonMcKinney** for the idea of using `pd.crosstab`!

Initially, I was going with basic `groupby`:

```py
df = df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']))
tally = df.groupby(['Date', 'Type of vaccine']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

tally.cumsum().plot()
```

Comment: Nice addition of `.cumsum`

Comment: Initially I was going with `groupby` and `unstack` (see updated answer). Good reminder about `crosstab` (I don't use it often enough).

Comment: `pivot` is for plotting when you need a wide dataframe with no aggregation, `pivot_table` for the same but with an aggregation, and `crosstab` is for when you want `pivot_table` but the aggregation values are also the column (so usually when you only have 2 columns, instead of at least 3).